# Is there a way to see how I voted to close?

Tags: feature-request

I see through the activity part of my profile that I voted to close a question but I don't see anywhere that says what my reasoning was (there are three different reasons on the question so far).  Is there no way to see which of the reasons is the one I submitted?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to see this information (I can't find it anywhere). I don't know for sure it's not available, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently unsupported; but you are welcome to submit a feature request on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: related MSO feature-request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/)